# How to add a row with composite keys (HFSQL)

Tags: python, sql, database, pyodbc, hyperfilesql

in my company I am trying to make a program that allows us to complete our erp using its hfsql database, for example I would like to be able to add item movements, but in my last 2 columns of my table they are composite keys . When I ignore them I have an error that the number of values ​​is not equal to the number of columns and when I put the composition of the values, I have an error that tells me that these are composite keys that I cannot fill.

I tried different code